# how to calculate vat using foreign key EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, model, controller, google-play

I have an issue with calculating VAT,

i have product model

```
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }/*Product name english*/
        public string? TitleAr { get; set; }/*Product name english*/
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SKU   { get; set; } /*ISBN*/
        [Required]  
        public string SupplierName { get; set; } /*Productname*/
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="List Price")]
        [Range(0,1000)]
        public double ListPrice { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Price for 1-50")]
        [Range(0, 1000)]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Price for 50+")]
        [Range(0, 1000)]
        public double Price50 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Price for 100+")]
        [Range(0, 1000)]
        public double Price100 { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
         public List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    }
```

and Category model which contain vat

```
 public class Category
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [MaxLength(30)]
     [DisplayName("Category Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; } /*English name*/
     public string? NameAr { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Display Order")]
     [Range(1,100)]
     public int Display Order { get; set; }
     public int Vat {  get; set; }
 }
```

i have implemented order details table that include order total which i will calculate vat there before insert command

how do i retrieve Vat value for each product then i will do the needed calculation?

here is my calculation code

```
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
ShoppingCartVM = new()
{
    ShoppingCartList = _unitOfWork.ShoppingCart.GetAll(u => u.ApplicationUserId == userId,
    includeProperties: "Product"),
    OrderHeader = new()
};


foreach (var cart in ShoppingCartVM.ShoppingCartList)
{
    cart.Price = GetPriceBasedOnQuantity(cart);
    ShoppingCartVM.OrderHeader.OrderTotal += (cart.Price * cart.Count);
}
return View(ShoppingCartVM);
```

}
along with this method

private double GetPriceBasedOnQuantity(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
{

```
if (shoppingCart.Count <= 50)
{

    return shoppingCart.Product.Price;
}
else
{
    if (shoppingCart.Count <= 100)
    {
        return shoppingCart.Product.Price50;

    }
    else
    {
        return shoppingCart.Product.Price100;
    }
}
```

}

regards

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to post the code where you read/create this order and want to calculate the total in order to get a specific example/help.

Generally speaking once you know what products you need to include if you need to fetch those products and category data you can use projection such as:

```
_context.Products
    .Where(p => productIds.Contain(p.Id))
    .Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Price, p.Category.Vat })
    .ToList();
```

... where "productIds" assumes a collection of the product IDs to include in the order.

You might want to also include the Price50/100 as well based on the order product quantity etc. From there you have a collection of product information including the related category Vat to use to calculate your order's total price.